# Выровнять две ссылки, чтобы они были на одном уровне (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

[image: Нужно, чтобы все было на одном уровне]
Прикрепил код, желательно, чтобы было все исправлено в нем. Спасибо) [![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

```css
/* NAVIGATION */
.menu {
  border: 12px solid #1a082b;
  background-color: #1a082b;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.links {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-left: 250px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.75;
  vertical-align: 10px;

}

.one:first-child{ /* У первой ссылки нечего отделять*/
  margin-left: 0;

}

.one:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.three:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.four:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.choose {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}




/*************************/

/* BodyNav*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>TrendShop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="ims">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="links">
          <a href="#" class="one">Скриншоты</a>
          <a href="#" class="two">Трейлер</a>
          <a href="#" class="three">Отзывы</a>
          <a href="#" class="four">Новости</a>
        </div>
        <div class="choose">
          <a href="#" class="wom">Жен</a>
          <a href="#" class="men">Муж</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="BodyNav">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: как можно что-то исправить в коде, если он картинкой? прикрепите нормальный код

Comment: Вы предлагаете ваш код перепечатать?

Comment: Если вставите код как положено, в виде сниппета, я вам, так и быть, помогу и даже тоже кодом ,а не скриншотом.

Comment: Извините, забыл прикрепить. Вот, всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь flex который назначается только родителю , смотрите пример в сниппете

В [песочнице](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qzRJxQ) я просто для примера адаптировал это меню

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #1a082b;
}

.menu,
.links,
.choose {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.links {
  width: 50%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.64s;
}

.choose {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Скриншоты</a>
    <a href="#">Трейлер</a>
    <a href="#">Отзывы</a>
    <a href="#">Новости</a>
  </div>
  <div class="choose">
    <a href="#">Жен</a>
    <a href="#">Муж</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Назначать бесполезные class для ссылок не имеет смысла